# Desire line mapping with Raspberry Pi and Python

Tags: raspicam, python-3

Desire lines normally refer to paths created by humans as a result of excessive use, as that path is the most efficient form of transportation. So if I mount my Pi Camera looking at an intersection, how could I map the desire lines for that intersection using my RasPi and camera? I am more thinking about tracking where people come from to get to a specific point.

Comment: you talking road traffic?

Comment: foot traffic most likely, though mabye road later

Comment: What mean by "map"?  Like this? (1) Rpi + camera on a drone, (2) Flying camera follows the foot steps of a "foot", (3) Traces the path of the "foot" on a map, (4) Android app shows the map with my dog's foot step sequence as a "path"?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the "intersection" and "desire lines" parts of your question.  Let me try again. (1) Your Rpi camera is glued to a lamp post at the intersection. (2) The fixed position camera traces the footsteps of all dogs and cats crossing the intersection, shows their footstep time sequences as "lines". But now, what do you mean by "desire lines"?

Comment: @tlfong01 your last comment is _exactly_ what I want to do. How would I do that?

Comment: Still not clear what are "desired lines".  Let me imagine: A city not too far from mine is a "cat" city.  Their annual cat festival is world famous. Eaters everywhere fly over to enjoy yummy cat food (not "for" cats, but "of" cats!).  The smart city has fat cat detecting cameras hanging on the lamp posts of road intersections, streaming "cat walk" videos to the customers, who touch their "desired" cat on the xPad menu, and the hot pot will be ready in an hour.  You can also order takeaways, or bring your own cat! ... You cat eater?  Me too.  I enjoy sweet & sour chicken feet dim sum very much!

Comment: You are assuming readers know what you are talking about.  You really should explain in your question what you are trying to do.  "desire lines" is a technical term not familiar to people not in that line of work.

Comment: @tlfong01 Now that I think of it, I am using the word slightly wrong. Desire lines normally refer to paths created by humans as a result of excessive use, as that path is the most efficient form of transportation. I am more thinking about tracking where people come from to get to a specific point. Sorry, I am new to StackExchange.

Comment: @PotatoHeadz35, Many thanks for your clarification.  Your scenario actually matches one of my Micky Mouse AI NN porjects.  My scene is starts with the floor plan of a shopping mall of a 7 stories, each with 40 shops surrounding the middle square. Now the CCTV camera is at the ceiling some 200 ft above ground, monitoring 12 x 7, the shoppers moving in the big square.  Now the big square is divided into 10 x 10 small squares, and the black 4x4 pixels (denoting heads in black) are counted every seconds.  The big data is analized to find the following: (1) Which shop is most popular? / to cont ..

Comment: (2) Is there a time sequence of shoppers visiting Shop A and then Shop B, Floor X and then Floor Y etc. It is like the Cambridge University''s "Game of Life" puzzle, but a bit more complicated: (a) Game of Life "wraps" the boundary squares to the opposite boundary.  Our game of shoppers "wraps" the square at the four escalators (stair cases ignored) to the upper or lower floor.  Game of Life is famously played using APL (A Programming Language), a mathematical "one line" programming language. Our project uses raspbian eLUA engine, ...

Comment: @PotatoHeadz35 Have a look at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/. It’s an old bookmark so will need work to get it going I expect. I’ve never tried the code but given it’s age a Pi 4B would be a big plus.  Not sure how you would handle multiple targets as the beer theft is a bit contrived :)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you’re trying to establish patterns of life using a camera to track individuals. A Pi I think will be hard pushed to process the imagery to recognise separate individuals. You might be better using pressure pad sensors and multiple Pi spread around the area. You could then fuse the pressure pad readings to establish individual tracks. That is a non trivial mathematical problem esp when you’re tracking multiple individuals. Tool wise Python may not be the best solution. I’d look at using Wolfram Mathematics and Google the likes of track before detect for the fusion aspects. Good luck, you’ll need it!